# Integral of exponential function?

Tags: integration, exponential-function

How do i solve this one using exponential function? should i bring up x^2?
$$\int\frac{2^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}dx$$

Comment: U-subsitution is a nice way to proceed, do you see anything in the integrand that would be useful to set equal to u?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$t=(1/x)$$,$$-dt=\frac{dx}{x^2}$$$$\int2^tdt=\frac{2^t}{\ln2} +C$$

Comment: why the derivative of t become negative? and became x^2?

Comment: $t=x^{-1}$ now differentiate it $dt=-x^{-2}dx$